# Sending JSON to an AWS SageMaker endpoint from an Android app (Java)

Tags: amazon-web-services, amazon-sagemaker

I need to send a JSON to an AWS SageMaker endpoint from an Android app (Java)  and everything I have found online does not work.

Can anybody please help with some insights or directions or maybe even some code that sends the JSON and receives a response from the endpoint?

The AWS documentation was not very helpful as I am not entirely sure what classes to import and what dependencies to use and also if possible can anyone please direct me what to change in the Android manifest and in the Gradle build module? Thank in advance!

I tried surfing through every solution I could find and they always returned errors, that I could never solve after intensive internet surfing and also reading the aws java documentation, but it just brought me more questions than answers.

I created an Inference Endopoint with aws and I want to send a json file and unpacking within sagemaker to be able to start the inference on some images.

*I moved a bit forward since I posted the question*

For reference, this is what I am trying to achieve(gotten from another project I did in the past in python):

```py
body = json.dumps({"input_key": input_key, "webcam": webcam})
content_type = 'application/json'
ioc_response = client.invoke_endpoint(
        EndpointName=endpoint_name,
        Body=body,
        ContentType=content_type)
```

My current code is:

```java
package Utils;

import com.amazonaws.auth.DefaultAWSCredentialsProviderChain;
import com.amazonaws.services.sagemakerruntime.AmazonSageMakerRuntime;
import com.amazonaws.services.sagemakerruntime.AmazonSageMakerRuntimeClientBuilder;
import com.amazonaws.services.sagemakerruntime.model.InvokeEndpointRequest;
import com.amazonaws.services.sagemakerruntime.model.InvokeEndpointResult;

import java.nio.ByteBuffer;
import java.nio.charset.StandardCharsets;
public class SageMakerUtils {

    private final String json;

    public SageMakerUtils(String json) {
        this.json = json;
    }

    public String run(){
        AmazonSageMakerRuntime client = AmazonSageMakerRuntimeClientBuilder
                .standard()
                .withCredentials(new DefaultAWSCredentialsProviderChain())
                .build();

        InvokeEndpointRequest invokeEndpointRequest = new InvokeEndpointRequest();
        invokeEndpointRequest.setContentType("application/json");

        invokeEndpointRequest.setBody(ByteBuffer.wrap(this.json.getBytes(StandardCharsets.UTF_8)));
        invokeEndpointRequest.setEndpointName("my-endpoint-name");

        InvokeEndpointResult result = client.invokeEndpoint(invokeEndpointRequest);

        return StandardCharsets.UTF_8.decode(result.getBody()).toString();
    }
}
```

and I use the following depedency in my graddle script:
implementation 'com.amazonaws:aws-java-sdk-sagemakerruntime:1.12.190'

Now I start getting errors related to the build:

> 2 files found with path 'META-INF/DEPENDENCIES' from inputs:
> - C:\Users\MyPC.gradle\caches\modules-2\files-2.1\org.apache.httpcomponents\httpclient\4.5.13\e5f6cae5ca7ecaac1ec2827a9e2d65ae2869cada\httpclient-4.5.13.jar
> - C:\Users\MyPC.gradle\caches\modules-2\files-2.1\org.apache.httpcomponents\httpcore\4.4.13\853b96d3afbb7bf8cc303fe27ee96836a10c1834\httpcore-4.4.13.jar

To which I found the following fix:

```java
android {      
      packagingOptions {
        exclude("META-INF/DEPENDENCIES")
        exclude("META-INF/LICENSE")
        exclude("META-INF/LICENSE.txt")
        exclude("META-INF/license.txt")
        exclude("META-INF/NOTICE")
        exclude("META-INF/NOTICE.txt")
        exclude("META-INF/notice.txt")
        exclude("META-INF/ASL2.0")
        exclude("META-INF/*.kotlin_module") 
      }          
}
```

Yet I just keep diving in a blackhole of errors, the next error I got is:

No static field INSTANCE of type Lorg/apache/http/conn/ssl/AllowAllHostnameVerifier; in class Lorg/apache/http/conn/ssl/AllowAllHostnameVerifier; or its superclasses (declaration of 'org.apache.http.conn.ssl.AllowAllHostnameVerifier' appears in /system/framework/framework.jar!classes4.dex)

P.S.: I am using android SDK 33:

```java
    defaultConfig {
        applicationId "com.example.myapp"
        minSdk 33
        targetSdk 33
        versionCode 1
        versionName "1.0"

        testInstrumentationRunner "androidx.test.runner.AndroidJUnitRunner"
    }
```

There is very few documentation regarding aws sagemaker in android studio and any help is more then welcome. Thanks in advance!

Comment: You question needs much more details. What SageMaker operation are you trying to invoke. Saying sending to an aws sagemaker endpoint is vaque. WHat SDK are you using to work with Sagemaker. WHat code have you tried. If you are using code - show the logic.

Answer (score 1):

To work with AWS Services and Android - move away from **Java SDK V1**. Move to the [AWS SDK for Kotlin](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/sdk-for-kotlin/latest/developer-guide/home.html). You will get full benefits of the Kotlin programming language such as Coroutines. You do not get full benefits of Kotlin using AWS SDK for Java V1. The ***AWS SDK for Kotlin*** is the AWS SDK to work with Android and Android Studio projects.

See this section in the AWS Kotlin DEV Guide.

[Coroutines](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/sdk-for-kotlin/latest/developer-guide/coroutines.html)

We have an ANdroid development tutorial that shows you how to build an example Android app using this SDK. See the second link here in the ***AWS Code Library***:

[Build a publish and subscription application that translates messages](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/code-library/latest/ug/cross_SnsPublishSubscription_kotlin_1_topic.html)

This example app shows how to develop a native Android application with publish/subsciption functionality and the ability to translate messages by using the AWS SDK for Kotlin. It also shows an example of a successful Gradle build file.

Once you learn how to successfully use the KOTLIN SDK in an Android project (and not get the errors you are seeing using Java v1), then you can learn how to hook in the SageMaker API. You can find Kotlin SageMaker API examples here:

[Amazon SageMaker Kotlin code examples](https://github.com/awsdocs/aws-doc-sdk-examples/tree/main/kotlin/services/sagemaker)